# How to assign a constant value in a recursion relation

Tags: numerics, recursion

I use the code

```
fv = RecurrenceTable[{a[i] == 
     1/(i (i + 1)) (1/Sqrt[w] a[i - 1] + (2 i - 1 - e[i]) a[i - 2]), 
    a[2] == 1/6 (1/(2*w)+3 - e[i]), a[1] == 1/(2 Sqrt[w])}, a, {i, 3, 10}];
```

to evaluate the three-step recursion relation where

```
e[i_]:=e[i]=2i+1
```

after that I need to obtain the roots of fv, so I use

```
sol2 = N[Solve[fv[[1]] == 0, w]]
```

my main problem is that e must be calculated using max i, namely the code must calculate the value of e first, then must use i to calculate recursion relation, 
For example for i=3 , e becomes 7, then a[3] must be calculated that includes e[3] and a[2] and a[1](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/2pages.pdf), where a[2] must be calculated using e[3] again not e[2],
maybe some sort of a loop needed.
I really don't know how to address this  problem. Any idea?

The correct results for what I intend are:

i=3, w=0.05;

i=4, w=0.0182 and w=0.1900;

and so on.

**You can see the original paper which has introduced the above formula and the results [here](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/2pages.pdf). I have marked important formula. The results have been shown in the table.**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question - are you asking how to change your code such that `a[i]` is computed using `e[i]` everywhere, even for `a[i-1]` etc.?

Comment: @LukasLang yes, I explained it in my example.

Comment: @bbgodfrey sorry it was a mistyping, I corrected it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Sorry I forgot to type a 3 in a[2] formula. I corrected it, however just first case (i=3) gives correct answer but other results are wrong, I checked my formula but there was no mistake. Do you think two different roots for i>3 cause the mistake?

Comment: @Wisdom  How did you obtain the values of `w` in the question for `i = 4`?  Please show the equation you solved.

Comment: @bbgodfrey In fact I'm trying to reproduce the results of a paper using a code. I added it to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that doesn't use `RecurrenceTable` but rather simply defines recursive functions for this (note the addition of a second argument to `a`):

```
e[i_] := 2i+1
a[i_] := a[i, e[i]];

a[i_, e_] := 1/(i (i + 1)) (1/Sqrt[w] a[i - 1, e] + (2 i - 1 - e) a[i - 2, e]);
a[2, e_] := 1/6 (1/(2*w) + 3 - e);
a[1, e_] := 1/(2 Sqrt[w])
```

To create a similar list as you would get from `RecurrenceTable`:

```
fv = Table[a[i], {i, 3, 10}]
```

Comment: your code does't work and yields a e[3], e[4] and so on.

Comment: @Wisdom edited to include your definition of `e` as well (without the memoisation)

Comment: Ohhhh Thank you soooo much, it returned my desire results exactly.

Answer (score 1):

With the clarification provided by the reference now given in the question, the desired solution is easily obtained.

```
a[1] := 1/(2 Sqrt[w]); 
a[2] := 1/6 (1/(2 w) + 3 - e); 
a[i_] := 1/(i (i + 1)) (1/Sqrt[w] a[i - 1] + (2 i - 1 - e) a[i - 2]);
Flatten[Table[NSolve[(a[i] /. e -> 2 i + 1) == 0, w], {i, 3, 10}], {{3}, {1}}][[1]] // Values

(* {{0.05}, 
    {0.190065, 0.0182686}, 
    {0.0404842, 0.0086731}, 
    {0.156634, 0.015429, 0.00478921}, 
    {0.0344873, 0.00753932, 0.00292085}, 
    {0.134788, 0.0134812, 0.00424987, 0.00191167}, 
    {0.0302949, 0.00671401, 0.0026321, 0.00131905},
    {0.119177, 0.012046, 0.00383985, 0.0017433, 0.000948279}} *)
```

The reciprocals of these values are precisely those given in the reference.  Note that `Flatten[. . ., {{3}, {1}}][[1]]` merely eliminates unnecessary pairs of curly brackets.